# Magento 2.3.0 Get product attribute name in phtml in CMS Block

Tags: magento2, php, product-attribute, magento2.3

I have a attribute called

> Artist

It has several artist names

**XYZ

ABC

RST**

I need to be get the artist name associated to the current product page via a call to a phtml in a CMS Block.

What do I need to put in the block file and in the phtml file for this?

I've tried this [solution](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-attribute-id-name-value-from-attribute-code/) but I'm unsure how to go about it or if even a recommended method of doing it.

---

UPDATE

What I'm looking for is to use a short code to call the attribute name within the short description block, as follows, rather than changing the view xml file to get and position the attribute name on the product page.

```
<p>Painting by {{block class="" template=""}} in oil on canvas</p>
```

Where

```
{{block class="" template=""}}
```

= attribute artist name

Comment: As per my understating you want to call a phtml in static block and html will be responsible for getting some product attribute.You will call static block on product view page .Right ?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Ok, let me try some solution for you.

Comment: You can directly call attribute to view page. why creating `phtml` and `static block` ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - Thanks to [Pawan](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44340/pawan) for helping with part of the solution.

> **Solution** - modified from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403334/magento-2-2-append-attribute-name-to-product-name-h1).

In the artist.phtml file

> ```
> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/artist.phtml
> ```

I used the following code.

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$product_name = $product->getName();
$attr_exists = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('artist');

if ($attr_exists){
    $attr_name = $product->getAttributeText('artist');
}

echo $product->getAttributeText('artist');
?>
```

and called it from with a CMS Block using the following shortcode

> {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="artist"
>   template="Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml"}}

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call product attribute in following file.

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Using following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.custom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.stock.sku">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Note:** You need to replace `short_description` with your new attribute code.
You can also change display position of product attribute.

**Update I**

If you want to manage it from static block you need to create a static block with identifier `artist_block` with following content

> {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="artist" template="Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml"}}

Now create `artist.phtml` at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/artist.phtml

with following content

```
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
echo $product->getId();
echo $product->getName();//you can change attribute here
```

Now you need to call static block at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

by following code:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="artist.block" after="product.info.stock.sku">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">artist_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: I'm trying to use a short code to call the attribute name within the short description block, so this solution will not work. I have updated my question above.

Comment: See my update in answer and let me know if works.

Comment: Thank you, solution partly works, it only gives me the current product name, I need to get the attribute name. Also the phtml files for are in this location app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product so how do I modify the block call location accordingly.

Comment: You can use $product->getArtist();

Comment: It doesnt work, this is what I'm using <?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
echo $product->getId();
echo $product->getArtist();
It only shows the number 1 followed by the product name as such "1productname"

Comment: What is your attribute code and type ?

Comment: attribute code = artist | 
type = dropdown. 

Product page shows a painting, the attribute of that painting is artist, so different paintings will have different artist names, so I'm using the product short description to call the phtml shortcode to show artist name in the short description.